# CONCAT and INNER JOIN - Constraining records with lookup table

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below creates a hierarchical relationship with tables and records:

```
program -> program_outcome_group -> program_outcome -> unit -> leaning_event
```

Based on the following tables structures:

```
Table program:
        +------------+----------------+
        | program_pk |  program_name  |         
        +------------+----------------+
        
Table program_outcome_group: 
        +--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
        | program_outcome_group_pk |  program_outcome_group | program_fk |            
        +--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
        
Table program_outcome:         
        +--------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
        | program_outcome_pk | program_outcome | program_outcome_group_fk |          
        +--------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+

Table unit:         
        +---------+-----------+
        | unit_pk | unit_name |          
        +---------+-----------+
    
Table learning_event:     
        +-------------------+---------------------+---------+
        | learning_event_pk | learning_event_name | unit_fk |            
        +-------------------+---------------------+---------+
    
Table program_outcome_unit_lookup:     
        +--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
        | program_outcome_unit_lookup_pk | program_outcome_fk  | unit_fk |            
        +--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

The query below works for this.

The query currently does not do any secondary matching on lookup table `learning_event_program_outcome_lookup` for `learning_event` records matching to program_outcome.

Instead it just shows all learning_event records with a relationship to the parent unit via `learning_event.unit_fk`.  I need learning events in the parent to be constrained depending on match with the grand parent program_outcome.

```
Table learning_event_program_outcome_lookup:     
        +------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
        | learning_event_program_outcome_lookup_pk | learning_event_fk | program_outcome_fk |            
        +------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

How can the `learning_event` records be also constrained by `learning_event_program_outcome_lookup`?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this??

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
           p.program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pog.program_outcome_group_pk) AS global_id,
           pog.program_outcome_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program:', pog.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome_group pog
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', po.program_outcome) AS global_id,
           po.program_outcome AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome po
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome, ',unit:', u.unit_name) AS global_id,
           u.unit_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit u
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome pro ON pro.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name, ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN unit u2 ON le.unit_fk = u2.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome pro2 ON pro2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dP1NZDfBLjD5ADKnWYNv3u/1)

Comment: It's hard to get a handle on what you're asking, but if you're looking to join a table to restrict row output across a suite of unions you either have to join it within every individual query that you then union or you have to select a value on each query that you will then use to join the restriction table in after the unions are done

Comment: Currently all learning events are being shown where learning_event.unit_fk = unit.unit_pk.  I want to ALSO restrict the learning events from units based on learning_event relationships with program outcomes as indicted in the learning_event_program_outcome_lookup table

Comment: Maybe just add the required join to the last UNION ALL statement? [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dP1NZDfBLjD5ADKnWYNv3u/2)

Comment: @user14717238  That might be the answer, let me test.

Comment: @user14717238  Put that into an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this constraint, add the JOIN `learning_event_program_outcome_lookup` by `learning_event` and `program_outcome` to the last UNION ALL statement:

```
JOIN learning_event_program_outcome_lookup lepol 
      ON lepol.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk 
     AND lepol.program_outcome_fk = pro2.program_outcome_pk
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dP1NZDfBLjD5ADKnWYNv3u/2)